# CSS - Bootstrap dropdown, with same class, positioned under different links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a problem with the position of my bootstrap dropdown class.

So, I have these two dropdown links in my table:

[image]

Whenever you click the down arrows, a dropdown will appear. The problem is, that the dropdown box, is always positioned to appear under the first arrow, like this:

[image]

If you click the arrows in the second row, the dropdown will **still** appear as in the picture above (under the arrows in the first row).

This is my code for the dropdown: (the table has the class `.referral-table`)

```
<table class="referral-table">  
<thead>
    <th width="4%" class="text-center">#</th>
    <th width="25%">Referral ID</th>
    <th width="20%">Referral Since</th>
    <th width="5%">Clicks</th>
    <th width="9%">Last Click</th>
    <th width="8%">AVG</th>
    <th width="10%"></th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
                        <td class="text-center">1</td>
                        <td>R1241415121151</td>
                        <td>Today</td>
                        <td class="text-center">3</td>
                        <td>Today</td>
                        <td>-,--</td>
                        <td>
                        <a href="#" style="color: #00975b;" class="dropdown-toggle  float-right" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i> </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu ref-moreinfo">
                            <div class="title">R1241415121151 - INFO</div>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Status</td>
                                    <td><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" title="Your referral is active."></i></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Came From</td>
                                    <td><i class="fa fa-question" title="http://google.com/images/wwwwwhaat"></i></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Earned</td>
                                    <td>$5.025</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </ul>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-center">1</td>
                        <td>R1241415121151</td>
                        <td>Today</td>
                        <td class="text-center">3</td>
                        <td>Today</td>
                        <td>-,--</td>
                        <td>
                        <a href="#" style="color: #00975b;" class="dropdown-toggle  float-right" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i> </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu ref-moreinfo">
                            <div class="title">R1241415121151 - INFO</div>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Status</td>
                                    <td><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" title="Your referral is active."></i></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Came From</td>
                                    <td><i class="fa fa-question" title="http://google.com/images/wwwwwhaat"></i></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Earned</td>
                                    <td>$5.025</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </ul>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>

            </table>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.referral-table .open>.dropdown-toggle{
    background-color: #fff;

    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-width: 1px !important;
    border-radius: 4px !important;

    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 9;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    right: 41px;

}
.ref-moreinfo {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-width: 1px !important;
    border-radius: 4px !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175) !important;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175) !important;
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    left: 607px;
    top: 51px;
    z-index: 8;
    padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

How can I implement it so that each dropdown is positioned under each arrow?

EDIT: BOOTPLY: http://www.bootply.com/QNV6nCrk9v

Comment: I am trying to replicate a JSFiddle of this, could you post one for me with a complete tag set at the very least? (you start with a `td` but end with a `tr`

Comment: @Austin Sorry! I have updated my HTML code with full tag

Comment: Thanks! I still cannot seem to find that caret button however, http://jsfiddle.net/HCD6E/

Comment: You don't have a `tr` around your `th`'s in your `thead`..

Comment: @Sebsemillia That shouldn't effect the bootstrap dropdown?

Comment: @oliverbj I don't think so, but it's still not a valid markup and that can influence anything in unpredictable ways.. ;)

Comment: btw: if you really want out help with your problem, I think it's best that you reproduce your own working example of the problem in a fiddle or bootply. Without this it's not really possible for us to identify the problem, as you can see in the fiddle of Austin..

Comment: @Sebsemillia I have created a bootply: http://www.bootply.com/QNV6nCrk9v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the bootply you provided doesn't really match the screenshot you provided, but after looking at your code I think the starting point is to give your `.open` element the `position: relative`.

```
.open {
    position: relative;
}
```

Since your `.ref-moreinfo` is positioned absolute, it needs a frame to be put in, you do this by giving the `.open` element said position. See [here](http://www.bootply.com/JQ1ToM6r10) how it is positioned differently now when clicked. I hope it helps you correcting your project.

Furthermore I noticed that you have another invalid markup, your elements in the `.ref-moreinfo` container need to be within a `li`, since your `.ref-moreinfo` is an `ul`.

Comment: I was about to point out that `ul` and `li` thing,  then I noticed you mentioned it already in your answer. +1